# Telegram Bot Telegraf: How to send a message after a successful payment

Tags: telegram-bot, telegraf

I am attempting to send a message/photo message after a successful payment has been made, but I am thrown the following error:

```
Error: Telegraf: "replyWithPhoto" isn't available for "pre_checkout_query::"
```

My code as follows:

```
bot.on('pre_checkout_query', (ctx) => {
    ctx.answerPreCheckoutQuery(true)
    .then(() => {
        let photo = //setup photo...
        let options = //setup caption and image url...
        ctx.replyWithPhoto(photo, options)
     })
})
```

Is there absolutely no way to follow up with some message after a successful payment has been made via the Telegram Bot API?

EDIT:

```
bot.on('pre_checkout_query', (ctx) => {
    let data = ctx.update.pre_checkout_query

    ctx.answerPreCheckoutQuery(true)
    .then(() => {
        let message = 'Thanks for the purchase!'
        bot.telegram.sendMessage(data.from.id, message)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure out how to do it thanks to this [post](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/558#issuecomment-381055996).

To send a message after the 'You have just successfully transferred $XXX to ...' banner, we need to listen for `successful_payment` message. Here's the implementation:

```
bot.on('pre_checkout_query', (ctx) => {
    ctx.answerPreCheckoutQuery(true)
})

bot.on('message', (ctx) => {
    if (ctx.update.message.successful_payment != undefined) {
        ctx.reply('Thanks for the purchase!')
    } else {
        // Handle other message types, subtypes
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Telegraf.telegram.sendMessage(chatId, text)` to handle this or `Telegraf.telegram.sendPhoto(chatId, photo)` to reply with photo

Comment: Hey there thanks for the tip. I used `bot.telegram.sendMessage()` and it kinda worked. But the message appears before the 'You have just successfully transferred $XXX to ...' banner. I would like my message to appear AFTER that banner.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I don't know how to handle it, sry